# Función js mediante la propiedad "onclick de un buttom que condiciona el texto que se muestra en un "alert()"

Tags: javascript, html, signalr

Buenas, estoy desarrollando una aplicación web basada en MVC que lista los eventos registrados en una base de datos. Los eventos se muestran listados en una tabla que se genera mediante javascript, ya que he implementado mediante SignalR para que cuando haya un nuevo elemento en la tabla ese se muestre sin necesidad de refrescar.

El problema es que al crearse la tabla de esa manera estoy teniendo muchos problemas a la hora de insertar un botón en cada fila con la explicación del tipo de evento que es.

Este es el script que me genera la tabla:

```js
function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
function getData() {
            var $tbl = $('#tableEvents');
            $.ajax({
                url: '../../index.aspx/GetData',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    if (data.d.length > 0) {
                        var newdata = data.d;
                        $tbl.empty();
                        $tbl.append(' <tr class="columns"><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NameEvent)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Protocol)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IP)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Port)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountID)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SessionID)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateEvent)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SecurityImpact)</th><th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Resolved)</th></tr>');
                        var rows = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < newdata.length; i++) {
                            rows.push(' <tr class="rowEvent"><td>' + newdata[i].NameEvent +
                                '</td><td>' + newdata[i].Protocol +
                                '</td><td>' + newdata[i].IP +
                                '</td><td>' + newdata[i].Port +
                                '</td><td>' + newdata[i].AccountID +
                                '</td><td>' + newdata[i].SessionID +
                                '</td><td>' + newdata[i].DateEvent +
                                '</td><td>' + newdata[i].SecurityImpact +
                                '</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="' + newdata[i].Id + '" value="' + newdata[i].Resolved + '"/></td><div class="container"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" onclick="myFunction()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></button></td></tr> ');
                        }

                        $tbl.append(rows.join(''));
                    }
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="tableEvents" class="table" runat="server"></table>
        </div>
```

La función GetData es la encargada de hacer las consultas a la base de datos para obtener la información de los eventos.

Haciendolo de esta manera tengo que pinchar muchas veces, muy seguido, en los botones que se crean en cada fila para que se accione la "alert()". Lo he intentado con un modal y con un pop up y tengo el mismo problema. En un principio sólo quiero solucionar para que pinchando una sola vez ya se accione como debe.

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Podrias indicar que as intentado hasta ahora ?

Comment: Quita el debugger, así permites que tu código se ejecute normalmente y evitas retardar tu navegador.